# How to save NLog.config in my class c#

Tags: c#, file, config, nlog

I want to save Nlog errors in file.How to NLog.config in my method?
To save the Log errors under the archive folder as

```
2010-06-05.log
2010-06-06.log
2010-06-07.log
2010-06-08.log
...
```

NLOG.config in that

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" 
        fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}.log" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

In my class;

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
       public void Method()
       {
           /* How do I save errors to an NLog file in here ?? */
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate Logger `instance` (usually it's one per class). Then you can call various logging methods available like `Error()`, `Warning()`, `Info()`, `Debug()` to log anything you want with appropriate level.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using NLog;

    public class MyClass
    {
       private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

       public void Method()
       {
           Logger.Error("My error message");
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: I did but folder did not occur

Comment: Did you invoke `Method()` ? Also, where did you place `NLog.config` file

Comment: I did new NLog.config file. Moving the  NLog.config  to app.config fixes the problem. Thank you soo much :))